# EntityFramework.BulkInsert is not giving any warnings or errors but isn't saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-bulkinsert

I've used BulkInsert in the past, but this is something I've not experienced.  Here is what is happening.

I'm creating a `List<tEntityType>` an after I've generated my list, I call `context.BulkInsert(myList);`.  Visual Studio isn't giving me any errors, and when I run the code and put a break point on the call, it appears to execute the bulk insert and continues.  However, when I browse the underlying table, there is no data in it?

To be clear, this is a code first, <s>SQL Compact</s>SQL Express 2014 database.  Also, within the same transaction scope, I am inserting records into other data tables and they are appearing.  So the transaction is executing, however, my bulk inserted records aren't showing up in the db.

I wish I could give more details, but I'm not getting any errors, exceptions or warnings.  Has anyone seen this and figured out a solution?

**MORE DETAILS**

In case you need to see the code, this is an abbreviation of my code.  I've only removed a bit of logic to build the underlying data and changed a few names to "protect the innocent."  This is, however, all that I'm doing.

```
        using (var ctx = new MyDbContainer())
        {
            using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
            {
                Header hr = new Header{Name= "NewRecord"};
                ctx.Headers.Add(hr);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

                //Get some records to work on and bulk insert.
                List<Records> recs = new List<Records>();

                //Records are inserted into the Recs list collection...

                //The purpose of this is to show that other records are being added within the same TX and are being committed to the db on the SaveChanges() call.  These records will be in the db afterwards.
                ctx.OtherRecords.Add(new OtherRecord { /* Details... */ } );
                ctx.OtherRecords.Add(new OtherRecord { /* Details... */ } );
                ctx.OtherRecords.Add(new OtherRecord { /* Details... */ } );

                //Do the BulkInsert and save the data.
                ctx.BulkInsert(recs.ToList());
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                tx.Complete();
            }
        }
```

As annotated above, my bulk insert is part of a much large process.  First, I insert a header record.  I do this so that I can use it's `ID` field as a foreign-key value within my other records.  I insert a couple of records one at a time, then I call my bulk insert.

The database is saving the HeaderRecord as well as the OtherRecords.  I can see the data.  However, the bulk inserted Records are not in the database.  What could be going on?

*UPDATE*

I migrated to SQL Server Express 2014, from SQL Compact.  This still didn't fix the problem.  The most bizarre thing is that I can't get an exception to occur and give me more details.

Comment: If you looped through rateHistory and added them all then called SaveChanges does it work? This doesn't solve the BulkInsert problem but i'm curious if at least that much is working.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the EntityFramework.BulkInsert NuGet package does not yet support SQL Server Compact.

As indicated by a [discussion](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/discussions/538810) on the CodePlex site:

> SQL Server CE is not supported yet. It will be added probably in next release.

However, the [EntityFramework.BulkInsert.SqlServerCe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert.SqlServerCe/6.0.0) NuGet package already provides this functionality.

Comment: Sorry to take away the answer mark.  I moved to SQL Server Express 2014, and it's still not working.  Also, the above mentioned NuGet package didn't work either.